# How to properly handle the case when Cosmos DB emulator is not running?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-cosmosdb

I have a few Unit Tests (C#) that initialize a database and two collections with random data for the testing in the Cosmos DB emulator. My problem is that when I have not already started the emulator (or if I close it when the tests are running) the tests just hang.

My goal is to get an error message when something like this happens, instead of waiting blindly. Can this be done and how?

My tests get stuck in the following command:

```
DocumentClient
    .CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(ValidCosmoConfig.Database)
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try connecting to the emulator when it isn't running I see a `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException` thrown with message
"Response status code does not indicate success: InternalServerError (500); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; Reason: (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.);".

The inner exception is a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` (message "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.").

Depending on your unit testing library it may be possible, in the case of this error to completely abort when this case is detected.

Comment: I am not getting anything back. The first method that is called, and the program stucks there, is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync`.

Comment: Is the unit test framework you are using just converting an exception into a test failure?

Comment: It simply doesn't throw anything. It just gets stuck there and I have to kill it. The only solution that I found till now is to use `OpenAsync` at the beginning and exit when it throws an error. The timeout simply does not seem to work, for unknown reasons.

Comment: I updated a little my question and posted also an answer, if they can help you a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found in order to terminate the unit tests when the Cosmos DB emulator is not running, is to use before everything else the following code:

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource(ValidCosmoConfig.RequestTimeout);
try
{
    DocumentClient.OpenAsync(source.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

The `OpenAsync` throws indeed an exception and I can terminate the test immediately, but still, I do not understand why it just gets stuck in the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync`, nor why the timeout options that I am setting do not work.

Comment: Sync over async is an antipattern because it leads to weird edge cases. If your unit test framework cannot handle async methods you need a better framework.

Comment: Could you provide more information? I am currently running the db set up in the constructor of the base test class, which cannot be declared as async. What do you suggest?

Comment: I would do the DB connection when it is required, this avoids adding wait before needed (and particularly if never needed).

Comment: I see, but now we get back to initial problem. This seems to help me stop the program when the DB is not running, instead of stucking in the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync`. What can I do?

Comment: It is always the case with connections to resources over the network (even if completely internal to one machine) that time has to be given for a response (the speed of light applies): the "remote" machine might just be slow.
In a test case you could look at checking for the emulator running, but that is subject to changes in the emulator breaking your tests.